# How to get Nodejs response object from the outside of the routing function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Nodejs as a back-end. I am facing a problem with getting a response object from the outside of the router function. In first routing function i can do to console the response object but in second routing function i can not able to get the values in to console.

I declare the variable in first. In first routing function i have send the response values in to variable but can't able to get the values in another routing function.

```
let userNames;

router.get('/getUsers', function (req, res) {
    const users = [
    {name: 'Mark'},
    {name: 'Rafallo'},
    {name: 'Samir'},
    ]
    this.userNames = users; // will be response json
    console.log('userValues', this.userNames); // able to get the json in to console
    res.send(users);
})

router.get('/demoUser', function (req, res) {
    console.log('userValues', this.userNames); // unable to get the json in to console
})
```

How to get values from one's routing function in to another routing function.
Thanks.

Comment: try changing `this.userNames` to `userNames`

Comment: thanks. i got this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a *variable* use the variable name (`userNames`). It isn't a property of any object, so don't use `this`.

Generally, you don't want to do this though. You'll get race conditions between requests from multiple users and leak information to the wrong people.

Use a session instead.

Express has [middleware for this purpose](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer